# Discordpy - buttons as reaction does not work

Tags: python, discord.py

I would like to integrate more advanced interaction with users in my discord bot using buttons as reactions in bot posts. The idea is:
As an user I call !buttons and the bot responds me with a message and five buttons (the buttons should be in one row, not in one column) as reactions. When I click one of the buttons, the bot edits his message and replaces its content with something other (let's say with the name of the button).
I found out I can integrate this function with discord-components. When I try to use the simple usage of discord-components integrated into my bot:

```
...
bot = ComponentsBot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
...
@bot.command()
async def button(ctx):
    await ctx.send(
        "Hello, World!",
        components = [
            Button(label = "WOW button!", custom_id = "button1")
        ]
    )

    interaction = await bot.wait_for("button_click", check = lambda i: i.custom_id == "button1")
    await interaction.send(content = "Button clicked!")
```

After clicking the button I get "Failed" on Discord. Could somebody check out, what am I doing wrong? I only used the example from github and it didn't work https://github.com/kiki7000/discord.py-components/blob/master/examples/basic.py

Answer (score 0):

it's my first time posting on Stack, so i hope i'm of help.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ui import Button, View
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!",intents=discord.Intents.all())
@bot.command()
async def buttons(ctx):
    view = View()
    button1 = Button(label = "RAIN",style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple)
    button2 = Button(label = "CLOUDY",style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple)
    button3 = Button(label = "THUNDER",style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple)
    button4 = Button(label = "SUNNY",style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple)
    button5 = Button(label = "COLD",style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple)
    view.add_item(button1)
    view.add_item(button2)
    view.add_item(button3)
    view.add_item(button4)
    view.add_item(button5)
    async def button1callback(interaction):
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content="RAIN")
    async def button2callback(interaction):
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content="CLOUDY")
    async def button3callback(interaction):
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content="THUNDER")
    async def button4callback(interaction):
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content="SUNNY")
    async def button5callback(interaction):
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content="COLD")
    button1.callback = button1callback
    button2.callback = button2callback
    button3.callback = button3callback
    button4.callback = button4callback
    button5.callback = button5callback
    await ctx.send("Pick your Weather!", view = view)
```

This is the most understandable and easy way to do it, but it involves a lot of repetition due to the 5 buttons.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).